# When to call a reference property "delegate"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my app I have a storyboard with two scenes. The first one is a Summary-View-Controller and just shows some data. But you can tap on it and switch to a Edit-View-Controller scene where you can make changes. To report the changes back to the Summary-View-Controller the Edit-View-Controller will get a reference to his parent. When editing is done he will call a method in his Parent-View-Controller.

The property in the Edit-View-Controller looks like that:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <NameEditViewChangedProtocol> parentController;
```

My app works fine. That is not my problem. But in many tutorials I read a property like this is just called *delegate*.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <NameEditViewChangedProtocol> delegate;
```

I know what delegation is and how it works but for me *parentController* is a more meaningful name. *delegate*, that could just be anything. So my question is: When should I call a property like this delegate? Are there any rule how to use this name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know what delegation is and how it works but for me parentController
>   is a more meaningful name. delegate, that could just be anything.

I think you've answered your own question here. A *delegate* is a helper object that "could just be anything" as far as the delegating class is concerned. The name *parentController* assumes something specific about the relationship between the two objects. If you know that that relationship will always exist, then it's appropriate to use that name. On the other hand, if the two objects only happen to have that relationship, but the relationship isn't important to the fact that one object is using the other as a helper, then use *delegate* (or something similar).

So, is it necessary that the objects in question have a parent/child relationship? Are you sending messages to `parentViewController` specifically because it's the parent? Or is it conceivable that some other object could respond to the same messages?

Answer (score 3):

Usually names of properties of type `id<some protocol>` are the same as the last part of the protocol name, e.g. the 'delegate' property of a UITableView is a property of type `id<UITableViewDelegate>`, and the 'dataSource' property is of type `id<UITableViewDataSource>`.  If you name your protocols by their purpose, the name of a property of type `id<some protocol>` should come naturally from the protocol name.  For what it's worth, protocol names don't usually include the word 'Protocol'.

Andrew's answer about how to name the property could help you make a better name for the protocol as well, if you follow the protocol/property name correspondence which I explained.

Edit: Fix formatting throwing away `<protocol names>`

Comment: +1. So, you might call the parentController protocol "EditViewControllerParent", or, if it makes more sense for it to be a delegate, "EditViewControllerDelegate".

Comment: If you follow apple's style with NavigationControllers (self.navController), it should probably be 'self.parentController' or something more domain specific to your application

Answer (score 2):

Call it a delegate when it will be used to make decisions at runtime about how the edit view controller should behave, or is to be notified of events, incoming data, etc. Call it delegate if the edit view controller is to be reused in multiple contexts, and the delegate's class can be anything (possibly conforming to a delegate protocol).

It may make sense to call it parentController if you know that the relationship between the two is always going to be a parent-child relationship with the parent 'owning' the child, rather than the more abstract delegate relationship.